# Tags input with symfony/form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need to implement a tags input like https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags. I'm not quite sure how to implement the server-side part with symfony/form. I couldn't find any existing implementation and I'm not sure if I should try to somehow hack the ChoiceType or try to implement it separately.

Can you help me? Did I miss any existing solution?

Answer (score 1):

IMO this pattern fits [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) perfectly. [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) might be interesting as well. You just need to make sure that your javascript/jquery plugin can play along with the prototype feature.

Comment: Just a simple ChoiceType with option multiple set to true. Nothing else.

But I think he add problem by adding some select options with AJAX.

Comment: CollectionType has completely different UX so no I don't want that. I use it for different use cases but it is bad in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create a special FormType inherited from ChoiceType :**

```
    namespace Alsatian\FormBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

    class ExtentedChoiceType extends AbstractType
    {
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {  
            $resolver->setDefaults(array('choices'=>array()));
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return ChoiceType::class;
        }
    }
```

**2. Create a FormEvent Subscriber which populate your form with the tags you added at the client side :**

```
        namespace Alsatian\FormBundle\Form\Extensions;

        use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

        use Alsatian\FormBundle\Form\ExtentedChoiceType;

        class ExtentedChoicesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
        {
            public static function getSubscribedEvents()
            {
                return array(
                    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => array('populateChoices',-50),
                    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT   => array('populateChoices',-50)
                );
            }

            public function populateChoices(FormEvent $event)
            {
                foreach($event->getForm()->all() as $child){
                    if(get_class($child->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType()) === ExtentedChoiceType::class){
                        $this->populateChoice($event,$child->getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            private function populateChoice(FormEvent $event,$childName)
            {   
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $child = $form->get($childName);
                $type = get_class($child->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType());
                $options = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();

                $choices = array();

                $data = $event->getData();

                if(!array_key_exists($childName,$data)){return;}
                $data = $data[$childName];

                if($data != null){
                    if(is_array($data)){
                        foreach($data as $choice){
                            $choices[$choice] = $choice;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $choices[$data] = $data;
                    }
                }

                // Feel free to find a better way to reuse the defined options. In Sf 2.6 it was not possible here :
                $newOptions = array('route'=>$options['route'],'required'=>$options['required'],'multiple'=>$options['multiple'],'choices'=>$choices);
                $form->add($childName,$type,$newOptions);
            }
        }
```

**3. Usage :**

```
        namespace AppBundle\Form;

        use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

        use Alsatian\FormBundle\Form\ExtentedChoiceType;
        use Alsatian\FormBundle\Form\Extensions\ExtentedChoicesSubscriber;

        class ArticleType extends AbstractType
        {
            /**
             * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
             * @param array $options
             */
            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                $builder
                    ->add('tags',ExtentedChoiceType::class,array("multiple"=>true))
                    ->addEventSubscriber(new ExtentedChoicesSubscriber());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You got it a bit wrong. There is no ajax involved. I just need to accept any choices the user writes in the field - regardless whether they already existed or not. The existing choices are nice to have for suggestions but are meaningless otherwise.

Comment: OK, then you can remove all the stuf with the route. And juste take the part of it which populate the choice field with the submitted tags. It should work.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Know it should approximatively work in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. Why did you use -50 priority for the event listeners?

Comment: With this priority, you can add others listeners and they will be called after this. -50 is arbitrary. Must be < 0 to be before the listeners without priority.

Comment: And in PRE_SUBMIT it should be called before the ValidationListener

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there're many ways to do this. For example this is how I use it in my projects.

This custom form type returns an `array` when transforming from view to model data and expects an `array` when transforming from model to view data.

More info about data transformers in Symfony3: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#about-model-and-view-transformers

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class TagsType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($original) {
                return $original ? implode(', ', $original) : '';
            },
            function ($submitted) {
                if (!$submitted) {
                    return [];
                }

                $submitted = array_map(function($tag) {
                    return trim($tag);
                }, explode(',', $submitted));

                return $submitted;
            }
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

}
```

Depending on your frontend part this is by default rendered as an input field where you write tags separated by comma.

Comment: I also did so in the past, but since Select2 4.0.0, the Select2 works with an HTML "Select" input. That's why I changed my code to extend the ChoiceType.

Comment: This seems easy enough. I guess this answers the question - I should not try to extend ChoiceType but do it separately.

Answer (score 0):

My solution **compatible with [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2)** is to create a subscriber like this:

[image]

```
<?php   
namespace App\Form\Document\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

/**
 * Class AddTagFieldSubscriber
 * @package App\Form\Document\EventListener
 */
class AddTagFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private string $property;
    private string $label;
    private array $choices;
    private bool $isRequired;

    /**
     * AddTagFieldSubscriber constructor.
     * @param string $property
     * @param string $label
     * @param bool $isRequired
     * @param array $choices
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $property,
        string $label,
        bool $isRequired,
        array $choices
    ) {
        $this->property = $property;
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->isRequired = $isRequired;
        $this->choices = $choices;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT  => 'preSubmit'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $choices
     */
    private function addChoiceForm(
        FormInterface $form,
        array $choices
    ) {
        $form->add(
            'tags',
            ChoiceType::class,
            array(
                'label' => "letter.type.tags",
                'required' => $this->isRequired,
                'newFeature' => true,
                'choices' => $this->formatArray($choices),
                'multiple' => true
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        // Include the manually handed choices (in fact all the choices in the property are always accepted)
        $choices = $data[$this->property] ?? [];
        $this->addChoiceForm($form, $choices);
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        // Push default choices
        $this->addChoiceForm($form, $this->choices);
    }

    /**
     * Because ChoiceType expects the format "text"=>"key" and select2 form returns only text for new tags and
     * format "key"=>"text" for existing selection, ensure that all the entry are in a valid format
     *
     * @param array $orig
     * @return array
     */
    private function formatArray(array $orig) : array
    {
        $formatted = [];
        foreach ($orig as $item) {
            $formatted[$item] = $item;
        }

        return $formatted;
    }
}
```

And use it like that :

```
$builder
    ->addEventSubscriber(
        new AddTagFieldSubscriber(
            "tags",
            "letter.type.tags",
            false,
            $tagList
        )
    )
```

And in the twig :

```
$("#documentbundle_letter_tags").select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    theme: "classic",
    maximumSelectionLength: 3,
});
```